# Ajax script breaking at callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have this script which works once but I can't seem to replicate it inside the same document.

The JQuery:

```
$("document").ready(function() {

//This first instance works

if($("#add-menu").length) {
    $("#add-menu").change(function() {
        var datum = 'shortname=' + $(this).val() + '&table=projects';
        $.post('proj_query.php', datum, response);
        function response(data) {
            var jSON = $.parseJSON(data);
            $("label:contains('Title:') + input:first").val(jSON.title);
            $("label:contains('Medium:') + input:first").val(jSON.medium);
            $("label:contains('Dimmensions:') + input:first").val(jSON.description);
            $("label:contains('Work Blurb:') + textarea:first").val(jSON.blurb);
        }
    });
}

//This one doesn't work

if($("#id-blurb").length) {
    $("#id-blurb a").click(function() {
        if($("#edit-menu").val().length) {
            var datum = 'shortname=' + $("#edit-menu").val() + '&table=projects';
            $.post('proj_query.php', datum, responseB);
            function responseB(data) {
                var jSON = $.parseJSON(data);
                $("#id-blurb textarea").val(jSON.blurb);
            }
        }
    });
}
});
```

When I test by running alerts, I get alerts right up until I add the callback function (the one called 'responseB'). Then it stops generating them. So it seems it's finding the document, and it seems to be accepting the data, but that's about it. After that nothing happens.

proj_query.php looks like this:

```
<?php
require_once ('../functions/functions.php');
connectDB('../functions/login.php');
require_once("session.php");

if(isset($_POST['shortname'])) {
  $shortname = $_POST['shortname'];
  $table = $_POST['table'];
  $query = "SELECT title, medium, description, blurb FROM $table WHERE shortname='$shortname'";
  $result = mysql_query($query);
  $results = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);
  print_r(json_encode($results));
}
?>
```

The HTML is this (but you may not need that):

```
<div id="change" class="grid_4">
<h3>Edit a Project</h3>
<form method="post" action="index.php" name="editform" onsubmit="return validateEdit(this);">
    <input type="hidden" name="edit" value="yes" />
    <div class="field_container"><label>Project Name:</label>
<select id="edit-menu" name="shortname">
    <option value="">Select a Project...</option>
<?php //For creating the dropdown menu
    $query = "SELECT * FROM projects ORDER BY title ASC";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    if (!$result) die ("Server says: <br/>Database access failed: " . mysql_error());
    $rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
    for($i=0; $i<$rows; $i++) {
        $results[] = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);
        $option = $results[$i]['title'];
        $value = $results[$i]['shortname'];
        echo "<option value=\"$value\">" . $option . "</option>\n";
        }
?>
</select>
</div>
    <div class="field_container"><label>Title:</label><input type="text" name="title" maxlength="128"/></div>
    <div class="field_container"><label>Date:</label><input type="date" name="date" /></div>
    <div class="field_container"><label>Medium:</label><input type="text" name="medium" maxlength="256"/></div>
    <div class="field_container"><label>Dimmensions:</label><input type="text" name="description" maxlength="64"/></div>
    <div class="field_container"><label>Area:</label><input type="text" name="area" maxlength="16"/></div>
    <div class="field_container"><label>Video Number:</label><input type="text" name="video" maxlength="64"/></div>
    <div class="field_container"><label>New Shortname:</label><input type="text" name="new_shortname" maxlength="16"/></div>
    <div class="field_container" id="id-blurb"><label><a title="Click for old content">Work Blurb:</a></label><textarea class="blurb" name="blurb" rows="5" ></textarea></div>
    <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Edit Project" />
</form>
</div>
```

Banging my head on this one...

Comment: Do you get the following error in your console: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)  ?   If so, there may be a parse error in your php file. Check your php error log too

Comment: Try to check both your server-side and client-side logic. there may be an error in one of them.

Comment: In your .post call; responseB is a parameter which is supposed to call the responseB function. Wouldn't you need to call it as responseB() ?

Comment: @TheOneandOnlyChemistryBlob I have to learn how to use my console properly. Still kind of a newb at that. I thought about looking for an Internal Server Error but I don't know how to. I'll check the manual. Thanks.

Comment: Ah! The console is telling me that the call back function is not defined. At least that's something. Although I still don't know why it would say that.

Comment: I found a workaround (although I don't like it) by making the function generic and calling it from the callback parameter:
`code`
    if($("#id-blurb").length) {
     $("#id-blurb a").click(function() {
      if($("#edit-menu").val().length) {
       var datum = 'shortname=' + $("#edit-menu").val() + '&table=projects';
       $.post('proj_query.php', datum, function (data) {
        var jSON = $.parseJSON(data);
        $("#id-blurb textarea").val(jSON.blurb);
       });
      }
     });
    }
`code`